# How do I target the comment link inside the article?

Tags: css, hyperlink, target

so here is the HTML code for this page, and I am trying to change the color of the "Comment" link, how do I target it ?

```
        <p>Phasellus tincidunt tristique elit, nec scelerisque ante egestas sit amet. Nulla eu diam turpis. Etiam ac arcu nec augue sollicitudin elementum. Duis congue mauris eu augue congue commodo. Vestibulum eleifend suscipit augue, non laoreet sem interdum id. Aenean tempus odio sit amet ante malesuada posuere. Fusce dolor justo, lacinia eu varius a, tempor et arcu. Aenean in massa blandit, cursus erat sed, adipiscing orci. Morbi in odio dignissim velit dictum molestie. Phasellus leo augue, tempor a tortor et, eleifend laoreet tellus. Maecenas vel velit at arcu condimentum lobortis facilisis eu ipsum. Sed sit amet volutpat eros. </p>
        <p><a href="#">Comment</a></p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways:

1. Add an id to it. `<a id="whatever">`
2. Go down the pattern: `section article p a`
3. Add a class (similar to an ID) `<a class="whatever">`

I suggest that you use an ID. It is the best way to single out just this link. To select it with CSS by the id:

```
#your_id:hover {
    whatever-you: want;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but how would i target the hover ability of it? if i type in p:hove { text decoration none} it just targets all the links, but how do i target that one specifically? thanks for your answer btw

edit: it appears that did not target my comment link,and targeted all links within the article, if i were to add an id to it, do i type in  <a id="whatever"><p><a href="#">Comment</a></p> ?

Comment: @user3062391 #(((your_id))):hover {whatever you: want;}

Comment: @user3062391 glad it helped. Would you mind clicking the check next to this answer to accept it? It won't hurt, promise.